External login claims not received in ASP.NET MVC app on .NET 4.8 [For Google]
My Problem is why I get externalIdentity = null and no claims what's the reason? How can I solve it. I want to implement external login in my asp.net mvc 4.8 project. The code I wrote is given below. Carefully look at the codes. I use startup.auth.cs to add necessary implementation for client-Id and secret and rest of the code is written in my test controller.
 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable application cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/test/Login"), // Path to redirect on unauthenticated access
            });
          
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
            // Enable external sign-in cookie
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "xxx",
                ClientSecret = "xxx",
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google"), // Matches the redirect URI
                Scope = { "email", "profile" },
                Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = context =>
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:google:email", context.Email));
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            };
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);

        }
    }

My test controller methods are below
 public void GoogleLogin()
    {
        try
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleCallback", "Test") // Ensure this matches your callback action
            };

            // Request a redirect to the Google login provider
          
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, "Google");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception for debugging purposes
            // Example: log to a file or monitoring system
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "An error occurred during the login process.";
        }
    }

    public ActionResult GoogleCallback()
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the external identity from the ExternalCookie
            var externalIdentity = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            if (externalIdentity == null)
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Authentication failed. Please try again.";
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Extract claims from the external identity
            var claims = externalIdentity.Claims.ToList();

            // Extract user info
            var email = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
            var name = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Email not provided by Google. Ensure proper permissions.";
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            using (var dbContext = new MVCDBFirstEntities())
            {
                var siteUser = dbContext.SiteUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailId == email);

                if (siteUser != null)
                {
                    // Create application identity
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, siteUser.UserId.ToString()));
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, siteUser.UserName));
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, siteUser.EmailId));

                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(identity);

                    // Redirect based on role
                    return RedirectToAction(siteUser.RoleId == 5 ? "DropDownListMulSaveUsingAjaxPop" : "Admin", "Test");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "You are not registered. Please contact the admin.";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "An error occurred while processing your request.";
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

